# High-performance Python collections in Pharo

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, smalltalk, pharo

I try to avoid reinventing the wheel here. I want to confirm which of the high-performance python collections are the closest relative in Pharo:

**A Counter is a Bag**

- Python: Counter :
  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
- Pharo : Bag

**Dictionary which keeps the order of element insertion:**

- Python: OrderedDict
- Pharo: OrderedDictionary (found in the official image)

**Default dictionary is a Dictionary which create any items that you try to access**

- Python: defaultdict :
  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-object
- Pharo: ZnMultiValueDictionary?

(defaultdict can be used to create trees by using multiple keys):

```
d[key1][key2][key3] = value
```

**Double-end Queue (Deque): Supports adding and removing elements from either end**

- Python: deque (double-end queue) :
  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects
- Pharo: OrderedCollection?

Are my assumptions correct?
Is there another Collection subclass which is a better replacement for the above cases?

Comment: The answer is yes, your assumptions are correct. Note also that there is an `OrderedDictionary` class in Pharo 6.1.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia please post as an answer

Comment: @dcorking Thanks for encouraging me to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question admits two different answers. One short, the other more elaborated.

The short answer is yes, your assumptions are correct, `Count` is `Bag`, `OrderedDict` is `OrderedDictionary`, etc.

A more elaborated answer should include, at least, some few examples.

## **`Bag`**

This is an unordered collection that keeps track of repetitions (a.k.a. `occurrences`)

```
bag := Bag new.
bag add: 'Hello'; add: 3; add: 'Hello'.
self
  assert: (bag occurrencesOf: 'Hello') = 2;
  assert: (bag occurrencesOf: 3) = 1;
  assert: (bag occurrencesOf: 'foo') = 0
```

People not familiar with `Bag` have the tendency to use a `Dictionary` to count repetitions. That's not necessary, `Bags` are implemented exactly in this way, so there is no need to re-implement these collections.

Note the difference between a `Bag` and a `Set`. While both are unordered, the latter will keep only one entry of the same instance:

```
set := Set new.
set add: 3; add: 3.
set asArray = #(3)
```

while

```
bag := Bag new.
bag add: 3; add: 3.
bag asArray = #(3 3)
```

## **OrderedDictionary**

The difference between a `Dictionary` and an `OrderedDictionary` is that the former is unordered, while the latter remembers the sequence of additions. Because of this, they also behave as `OrderedCollections`, except that in this case the keys are *implicitly* the indexes `1`, `2`, etc. (recall that indexes are always `1`-based in Smalltalk.) The price we pay to have both features (generic keys and ordering) is mainly the duplication of the `values` collection. Note however that there are different alternatives for implementing these objects.

```
dictionary := OrderedDictionary new.
dictionary
   at: 'c' put: 'CC';
   at: 'b' put: 'BB';
   at: 'a' put: 'AA'.
dictionary asArray = #('CC' 'BB' 'AA')
```

however

```
dictionary := Dictionary new.
dictionary
   at: 'c' put: 'CC';
   at: 'b' put: 'BB';
   at: 'a' put: 'AA'.
dictionary asArray = #('AA' 'BB' 'CC')
```

basically because the `'a' hash < 'b' hash < 'c' hash` and it is therefore easy to foresee the inner allocation of values.